# Multiple composite keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is my entity:

```
{
     name: "",
     list: [{
       a: 1,
       b: 1   
     }]
}
```

I want to create two index, one by name and other for a and b together.

Example: trying to insert a=1 and b=1 twice must throw an error.

My mongodb driver is 2.

For name I did it work like that:

```
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MyEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending(m => m.Name), new CreateIndexOptions()
    {
        Unique = true,
        Sparse = true
    });
```

How can I do it for two properties in my list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C# side, you can use the `IndexKeys.Combine` helper to create such an index:

```
await coll.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MyEntity>.IndexKeys.Combine(
       Builders<MyEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending("list.a"), 
       Builders<MyEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending("list.b")), new CreateIndexOptions()
        {
            Unique = true,
            Sparse = true
        });
```

One odd behavior is that the constraints are [not enforced within a single document](http://www.waistcode.net/blog/unique-array-keys-in-mongodb) ([SERVER-1068](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068)) because indexes are not considered 'within' documents, so to speak. In other words, you could always insert a document `list : [ {a:1, b:1}, {a:1, b:1} ]`, i.e. a document that has a list that contains copies. That is easy to fix on the application side, but it might be good to know.

Comment: Nice, thanks, but your code are using a and b from outside my list object.
I have tried p.list.Select(myList => myList.a) but did not work too. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Ah, blech, sorry... Fixed it.

Comment: Did not work :(
I could insert several items with same values.

Comment: Then the problem must lie elsewhere. What does `db.foo.getIndexes()` return? It created the correct index on my machine, and it also enforces it correctly.